# Deleting Key from 2D Hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, key, 2d

My Hash looks like this

```
%hIDSet = (
      'TSASD2' => {
                    'country' => 'US',
                    'newid' => 'IMRAN',
                    'oldid' => 'TSASD4'
                  }

      'TS767' => {
                   'country' => 'DE',
                   'newid' => 'B90LKT',
                   'oldid' => '432553'
                 },
    );
```

when I do

```
my $sID = "TSASD2";
delete $hIDSet{$sID};
```

The output I get is

```
%hIDSet = (
  'TSASD2' => {},
  'TS767' => {
               'country' => 'DE',
               'newid' => 'B90LKT',
               'oldid' => '432553'
             },
);
```

My question is why the ID is not deleted completely?

Comment: It did delete. You must have tried to access the key again and so the key was vivified.

Comment: Obviously you should show us more code. A lot got changed during copy and paste.

Comment: Yes. I was recreating it in later part of the code. Although it was unintentional. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did delete the key, so you must have recreated it before dumping the hash again as in the following snippet:

```
my $sID = "TSASD2";
my %hIDSet = ( $sID => {} );
delete $hIDSet{$sID};
print(Dumper(\%hIDSet));  # It's gone
if ($hIDSet{$sID}{foo}) { '...' }
print(Dumper(\%hIDSet));  # You've recreated it.
```

---

Keep in mind that

```
$hIDSet{$sID}{foo}
```

is short for

```
$hIDSet{$sID}->{foo}
```

and that

```
EXPR->{foo}
```

means

```
( EXPR //= {} )->{foo}
```

so

```
$hIDSet{$sID}{foo}
```

means

```
( $hIDSet{$sID} //= {} )->{foo}
```

Note that this can assign to `$hIDSet{$sID}`.

Comment: That was one of the most helpful comment. Yes you were right, I was recreating it in later part of the code. I fixed that. Looks good now!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Cannot reproduce.

You are confusing the syntax for Perl hashes, and hashref literals. This signifies a hashref:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $hashref = {
  foo => 'bar', # ← note comma between items
  baz => 'qux',
};
delete $hashref->{foo};
print Dumper $hashref;
# $VAR1 = { baz => "qux" };
```

On the other hand, hashes are just lists:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash = ( # note parens
  foo => 'bar',
  baz => 'qux',
);
delete $hash{foo};
print Dumper \%hash;
# $VAR1 = { baz => "qux" };
```

The code your provided shouldn't compile because of a missing comma, and would fail to run with `use strict; use warnings;` because of the hash–hashref mismatch. Clean up the types, and it should work allright.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I fixed it. I was recreating the key.